# Woocommerce add if Customer is Guest to New Order Emails

Tags: email, woocommerce, checkout

Using Woocommerce I have guest checkout enabled. If a customer is a guest upon checkout, I'd like to then add the word "Guest" to the new order confirmation email right above customer details to quickly reference this customer was a guest and not a registered user already.

```
/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'add_guest_label_to_email', 5, 4 );
function add_guest_label_to_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {   
    // Check if customer is a guest
    if ( ! $order->get_user_id() ) {
        $guest_label = '<p><strong>Guest</strong></p>';
        echo $guest_label;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, truly appreciate that! Should I put this in my theme functions php file or the email file itself?

Comment: Add it to your functions.php theme file.